# Join multiple tables to show different content in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio

I'm using SQlite in my application and I have 2 tables. 
I have one table called "Cours" that populates my ListView. I have a second table called "Notes". It also populates another listView.

When I click in an Item of my first ListView, it goes to the other fragment. I can add some notes that will populate the 2nd listview. But I would like to do like this :

If i click in Item 1 of the 1 st list view, some notes are shown, if I click in the 2nd item, other notes are shown. For the moment, it doens't matter which item I click, all the notes are shown.

So;

**How do I join those tables so I can change the way I populate my ListView ? I mean, how do i say that Notes1 is for Cours 1 and Notes2 is for Cours 2? And then when I click in 1st item of the 1st ListView some notes are shown and if I click in another Item, others notes are shown?**

I know there's something about foreign key but I really don't know how to do, can you please explain me with some code ? (I will adapt it to mine)

I'm just asking for an exemple or some links in internet so I can learn..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you know that `foreign keys` could be related to what you want, why don't you just search about them?

Comment: i've searched but I don't understand how to do it..

Comment: How to do what? There are thousands of guides on the topic..

Comment: can you give me one ?

Comment: I will give you 400m+. https://www.google.es/search?q=sqlite+foreign+key+guide